# How can you use Envelope Rejection Sampling to generate samples from a posterior distribution?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, monte-carlo, posterior, rejection-sampling

Considering two independent random variables:
$$X \sim N(-1, 2^2) \;\; \text{and} \;\;Y \sim N(1, 1^2).$$

Assume we cannot observe $X$ and $Y$ directly but instead observe: $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 0.1^2)$ is the observational noise.

The conditional density of $(X,Y)$ given $R=r$ has density: $$p(x,y|r) = \frac{p(r|x,y)p(x,y)}{p(r)}$$ where $p(r|x,y)$ is the density of the normal distribution with mean $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and variance $0.1^2$ and $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$ is the joint density.

Now, assuming we have observed $R=3$, how can envelope rejection sampling be used to generate samples from the posterior distribution, considering $p(r)$ is unknown.

Then, using this, how can we estimate the posterior probability $P(X>Y|R=3)$?

Comment: Assuming $p(r)$ is unknown, then you haven't sufficient information to generate from the posterior distribution.  Do you have any *observations* of $R$?  Would you have prior distributions for the "hyperparameters" $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$?  BTW, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Comment: The parameters have the values $\mu_1 = - 1, \sigma_1 = 2, \mu_2 = 1, \sigma_2 = 1$ along with $\sigma_r = 0.1$ and I have the observation $R=3$.

Comment: Then *everything* is known, so what you appear to be asking is how to sample from the conditional distribution.  No estimation is required.  Indicating that "$p(r)$ is unknown" will confuse your readers.

Comment: I guess so, which I'm unsure how to do,  but then I need to then go onto estimating $P(X>Y|R=3)$

Comment: A suggestion: rewrite this post to describe the problem you really face.  In that fashion you are more likely to get direct, usable answers.

Comment: you're right, thank you

Comment: Please don't start a new thread just to edit your post!  That forces the community to start all over in considering your question, without the benefit of the previous dialog.   I have merged the two threads.  As far as the edit goes, does your interest lie in the *method* of sampling or in *being able* to sample?  Or does it focus on estimating the probability?  Or are these just side issues along the way to solving some other problem?

Comment: whuber: I'm interested in the method of envelope rejection sampling in this case, as well as estimating the probability.

Comment: Why, specifically that method? Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

The target distribution$$p(r|x,y)\times p(x) \times p(y) \propto\exp\left\{-50\left(r-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 -(x+1)^2/8-(y-1)^2/2\right\}$$is bounded from above by the prior
$$p(x) \times p(y) \propto\exp\left\{-(x+1)^2/8-(y-1)^2/2\right\}$$
which means that the prior can be used in the accept-reject algorithm. Expanding the first quadratic term does not directly help with the acceptance probability since
$$\left(r-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2=r^2-2r\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x^2-y^2$$
has a negative coefficient for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which one would like to eliminate from the upper bound.